# How can show text and image in next activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments, gridview

I have created android app like gallery which have some images using gridview fragment.

Functionality is working fine and image also showing in fragment gridview and Book activity but text not showing ( Text not set )

Here is my fragment code :

```
GridView grid;
    String[] web = {
            "Google",
            "Github",
            "Instagram",
            "Facebook",
            "Flickr",
            "Pinterest",
            "Quora",
            "Twitter",
            "Vimeo",
            "WordPress",
            "Youtube",
            "Stumbleupon",
            "SoundCloud",
            "Reddit",
            "Blogger"

    } ;
    int[] imageId = {
            R.drawable.person7,
            R.drawable.person1,
            R.drawable.person2,
            R.drawable.person7,
            R.drawable.person7,
            R.drawable.person7,
            R.drawable.person7,
            R.drawable.person7,
            R.drawable.person7,
            R.drawable.person7,
            R.drawable.person7,
            R.drawable.person7,
            R.drawable.person7,
            R.drawable.person7,
            R.drawable.person7

    };
    int[] fullimg = {
            R.drawable.person7,
            R.drawable.person1,
            R.drawable.person7,
            R.drawable.person7,
            R.drawable.person7,
            R.drawable.person7,
            R.drawable.person7,
            R.drawable.person7,
            R.drawable.person7,
            R.drawable.person7,
            R.drawable.person7,
            R.drawable.person7,
            R.drawable.person7,
            R.drawable.person7,
            R.drawable.person7

    };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_status,container,false);

        CustomGrid adapter = new CustomGrid(getActivity(), web, imageId, fullimg);

        //CustomGrid adapter = new CustomGrid(MainActivity.this, web, imageId);

        grid=(GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid);
        grid.setAdapter(adapter);
        grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {


                // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at " +web[+ position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                String value=(String)grid.getItemAtPosition(i);
                Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),Book.class);
                intent.putExtra("web", web[i]);
                intent.putExtra("imageId", imageId[i]);
                intent.putExtra("fullimg", fullimg[i]);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_status, container, false);
        return view;
    }
```

Here is my Book activity code where want to show text and image
image showing fine but i don't know how can i show text :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_book);


        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txttitle);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);


        //textView.setText(txttitle);
        //textView.setText(web[i]);
        imageView.setImageResource(getIntent().getIntExtra("fullimg", R.drawable.person7));


    }
```

Comment: so do you want to show text?

Comment: Yes i want to show both text and image on book activity

Comment: Maybe i don't understand the problem, but can't you just take the string as you take the imageId? textView .setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("web"))

Comment: I am doing some changes in your code, i give you the updated answer

Comment: Ok i will wait for your update

Comment: Is `web` key contains your text?

Comment: why you are using fullimg[] array?

Comment: I want to show two diffrent images on book activity

Comment: @AyanApps if the answer is working so i wouldn't update answer :)

Comment: you can update now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just fetch your text from Intent. I am considering `web` contains your text, then below code will fetch text for you

```
textView.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("web"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//textView.setText(txttitle);
//textView.setText(web[i]);
imageView.setImageResource(getIntent().getIntExtra("fullimg", R.drawable.person7));
```

You don't retrieve the passed text like you do for the image ;)

Answer (score 0):

Setting textview is just commented out. Just set TextView as similar to imageview:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_book);


    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txttitle);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);


    textView.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("web"))
    imageView.setImageResource(getIntent().getIntExtra("fullimg", R.drawable.person7));


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing variables to next activity through intent, Use Application class to store data and use anywhere in the app.

Comment: can you show me code of  Application class to store data

Comment: public class ApplicationLoader extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }
 
 private int data=0;
 
 public int getCompanyModel() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setCompanyModel(int data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
\n

In Manifest, 

<application
        android:name=".ApplicationLoader"..../>
\nset and get variable
\n
ApplicationLoader applicationLoader = (ApplicationLoader) getApplicationContext();
        applicationLoader.setCompanyModel();
        applicationLoader.getUpdatesModel();

Answer (score 0):

Put your constant which you are putting in intent while passing text value 
textView.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("YourKeyValue"));